# use host GPU on AVD cause app force close

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gpu

I am trying to use GPU with Intel HAXM on AVD.

I am using API 19, but when I check use host GPU and compile the code it always force close. But when its unchecked the code is working fine. What I am missing?

I am using NVidia GT 640M and my driver is up to date

I want to make AVD faster with HAXM, and I want to know how to fix my problem. I want to run OpenGL. Even tough I know that it can use other app like bluestack, but I just want to know why my AVD doesnt work with GPU. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bug is a problem reported to google.
You can follow the progress i think is not solve yet 100% but google still working in that.

This is the thread http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28529